in python mysql.connector why i see the this Errors?
I am a new user for python
import mysql.connector
try:
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
host='localhost',
user='root',
passwd=''
)
mycur=conn.cursor()
mycur.execute('creat database rakwan')
except mysql.connector.Error as r:
print(r)
the Error is:-
PS C:\\Users\\computer 8\> & "C:/Users/computer 8/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe" e:/PROGRAMING/python/Racoon/Learn/mq.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\\PROGRAMING\\python\\Racoon\\Learn\\mq.py", line 1, in \<module\>
import mysql.connector
File "e:\\PROGRAMING\\python\\Racoon\\Learn\\mysql.py", line 1, in \<module\>
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
pip install mysql
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

i hope some one help to incorage me to contenue in python....

Please fix your code and indentations.

Assuming you have the proper modules actually installed via pip, the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package error is likely occurring because you named your Python file mysql.py which is conflicting with the mysql-connector module.
Python will try to import mysql.connector from your script first, which is likely causing the issue.
Rename your Python file mysql.py to something else and try again.
Example:
mysql_connect.py:
import mysql.connector

try:
    # Create connection
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd=''
    )

    # Create cursor
    mycur=conn.cursor()
    mycur.execute('CREATE DATABASE my_test_database;')

except mysql.connector.Error as r:
    print(r)


thank you very much for your support . but error still the same...

Are you sure you have installed the module correctly??? pip install mysql-connector-python

when i do it again    :-  Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\computer 8\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (8.4.0)

Make sure no other files called mysql.py exist in your project. Could you edit your response to include full, formatted code, and file structure? Also uninstall any needless modules that aren't mysql-connector-python

the error now became :-
PS C:\Users\computer 8> & "C:/Users/computer 8/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe" e:/PROGRAMING/python/Racoon/Learn/mq.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\PROGRAMING\python\Racoon\Learn\mq.py", line 1, in 
from mysql import connector
File "C:\Users\computer 8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector_init_.py", line 34, in 
import _version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'

What exactly are you trying to do??? Where did the _version module come into play here and why are you trying to import it as a way to solve your current issue? Focus on the issue at hand: Your mysqli.connector issues. Don't worry about trying to uninstall every single module you have installed, just the ones pertaining to mysql, and then reinstall mysql-connector-python and try again.

Woo at last the problem finished . you Code done . Thanks very much

You should accept any answer by clicking the v sign accept button on the left. I gave @quietWind01 an upvote for the help on the import in my answer. :)

@Cow Appreciated.

@MohamedAbdElGhafar Glad it helped.

The pip installs you provided are not the official library, it can be installed with: pip install mysql-connector-python This is the official installation guide
Code:
from mysql import connector

try:
    with connector.connect(host='localhost',
                   user='root',
                   password='password') as conn:
        mycur = conn.cursor()
        mycur.execute('creat database rakwan')
except connector.Error as e:
    print(e)

I hope it can help you solve your issues.
More examples on mysql.com

Using import mysql.connector is fine usage.

@quietWind01 funny, I just tested that and yes, you're right.

from mysql import connector is probably better and formal, but don't take my word for it. I just know import mysql.connector works as well.

@quietWind01 ah well, thanks for the message on the mysql.connector. :)

thank you very much for your support . but error still the same...

@MohamedAbdElGhafar you need to remove all the old libraries and install the correct one as I wrote.

may i uninstall python completely and reinstall ?

@MohamedAbdElGhafar you can try. :)

the error now is :-    1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

@MohamedAbdElGhafar Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES This error is pretty self-explanatory. You were denied access to log in to the database. Double check your username (root) and your password are correct.

The problem finished . thanks very much .

@MohamedAbdElGhafar you should accept either answer by clicking the v sign underneath the arrows. :)
